# How to get year, month and day from seconds in PostgreSql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date

I'm trying to create three columns based on date in seconds format.

My `user.updated_at = 1521533490`

I would like to get year, month and day separately and put these formatted values to columns for example:

year -> 2018, month -> 11, day -> 23

Does someone know how can I do that in `pgSQL`?

Comment: Don't have three columns for date. Just store a date (or datetime) - but I think 1521533490 was yesterday (20th March), not 23rd November

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to get year, month and day separately and put these formated values to columns

Don't do that.

Use a single column of type `date` or `timestamp`, depending on your application. Not every combination of your three columns will be a valid date. But every value in a single column of type `date` *will* be a valid date.

If you need the parts of a date separately, use [PostgreSQL's date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this approche to get differents arguments, then you can do whatever you want:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1521533490); //2018-03-20T08:11:30.000Z
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(1521533490), 'HH'); // 08 Hour
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(1521533490), 'MI'); // 11 Minutes
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(1521533490), 'SS'); // 30 Seconds
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(1521533490), 'DD'); // 20 Day
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(1521533490), 'Mon'); // MAR Month
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(1521533490), 'YYYY'); // 2018 Year
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `EXTRACT` function.

```
SELECT to_timestamp(updated_at) "Date",
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (to_timestamp(updated_at))) "Year",
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (to_timestamp(updated_at))) "Month",
EXTRACT(DAY FROM (to_timestamp(updated_at))) "Day"
FROM users
```

Output

```
Date                  Year  Month  Day
2018-03-20T08:11:30Z  2018  3      20
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/afe0e/15/0

More information on the [EXTRACT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php) function.